# How to get Confirmation of email send or discarded in android

Tags: android

How can we get confirmation of Email send or discarded by any mail client of android.

I have tried startActivityForResult() but it not works. It returns Intent=Null and Resultcode=0 every time while send or discard pressed.

Thanks in Advance for your response.

Tejas

Answer (score 3):

> How can we get confirmation of Email send or discarded by any mail client of android.

Fortunately, this is not supported.

If you are sending data via `ACTION_SEND`, please allow the user to do with that data as they choose, including abandoning the "send" operation. You do not have a way to determine if the user does or does not "send" the information.